# Explicitly conversion of addres and payable

Tags: solidity, blockchain, contract-design

i can't understand this 
Explicit conversions to and from address are permitted for integers, integer literals, contact types and bytes20. However, Solidity prevents the conversions of address payable(x).

The address(x) can be converted to address payable in cases when x is of integer, fixed bytes type, or a literal or a contract that has a payable fallback function. When x is a contract without the payable fallback function, the address(x) is of type address.

Answer (score 1):

It is just an opinion but you have some reason

Given this variables:

```
address addressVal;
uint160 uint160Val;
bytes20 bytes20Valu;
address payable payableVal;
```

It will allow some conversion between address and payable

```
payableVal = address(uint160Val);
payableVal = address(bytes20Val);
```

And it will fail with the most obvious

```
payableVal = address(addressVal);
payableVal = addressVal;
```

(My opinion here is that all of the above should fail)

Fortunately it was introduced with solc 0.6 casting to payable that should work in all cases.

```
payableVal = payable(uint160Val);
payableVal = payable(bytes20Val);
payableVal = payable(addressVal);
```